# I don't understand this code in javascript

Tags: javascript

So we define this function with onClick as parameter:

```
    function createRemoveButton (onClick) {
      const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
      removeBtn.innerHTML = 'X';
      removeBtn.addEventListener('click', onClick);
      return removeBtn
    }
```

```
    function addTodoToDOM (todo) {
      const node = document.createElement('li');
      const text = document.createTextNode(todo.name);

      const removeBtn = createRemoveButton(() => {
        store.dispatch(removeTodoAction(todo.id))
      });
      node.appendChild(text);
      node.appendChild(removeBtn);

      node.style.textDecoration = todo.complete ? 'line-through' : 'none';
      node.addEventListener('click', () => {
        store.dispatch(toggleTodoAction(todo.id))
      });

      document.getElementById('todos')
        .appendChild(node)
    }
```

Question: How come there is no argument passed inside `createRemoveButton` when called inside the function above?

Comment: There is an argument passed. The argument is `() => {
        store.dispatch(removeTodoAction(todo.id))
      }`.

Answer (score 0):

`createRemoveButton` *is* called with an argument, the argument is a function, `() => { store.dispatch(removeTodoAction(todo.id))}`.

in javascript, we can pass functions as arguments. In `createRemoveButton`'s declaration, `onClick` will need to be a function, which then gets passed to the `addeventListener`, whose second argument has to be callback function.

Side note: any type *could* be passed in (i.e. `onClick` could be a string, null, whatever), because javascript doesn't check param types, but it would throw an error during runtime if it's not passing a function to the `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, functions are considered first-class objects. For this reason, you can pass them as arguments.

To make it more clear, you could change the code to:

```
const callback = () => {
        store.dispatch(removeTodoAction(todo.id))
      };

const removeBtn = createRemoveButton(callback);
```

More about functions as first-class objects: [https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/discover-the-power-of-first-class-functions-fd0d7b599b69/#:~:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20functions%20are%20first,returned%20from%20a%20function](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/discover-the-power-of-first-class-functions-fd0d7b599b69/#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20functions%20are%20first,returned%20from%20a%20function)

Comment: Thanks for your help!